# sed with mathematics operation

Tags: bash, replace, sed, terminal, grep

I have a text file with following structure

```
    <h2>Time 455</h2>
Random texts may contain numbers
    <h2>Time 460</h2>
Random texts may contain numbers
    <h2>Time 483</h2>
Random texts with numbers
    <h2>Time 555</h2>
Random texts with numbers
    <h2>Time 550</h2>
Random texts may contain numbers
```

I want to deduct (for example) 5 from number from each of the line containing h2 time

So the final output will be something like

```
    <h2>Time 450</h2>
Random texts may contain numbers
    <h2>Time 455</h2>
Random texts may contain numbers
    <h2>Time 478</h2>
Random texts with numbers
    <h2>Time 550</h2>
Random texts with numbers
    <h2>Time 545</h2>
Random texts may contain numbers
```

Note: Im using Mac terminal

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: sed is not a good choice for doing arithmetic operation and you'll have to show your effort in solving the problem

Comment: Instead of saying `Random texts may contain numbers`, show us some representative "Random texts containing numbers" in your input. `<h2>Time 455</h2>` qualifies as "Random texts containing numbers" so could that be your 2nd line as well as your first? If not, why not (apparently that text is not "Random" after all)?. Try harder to explain your requirements and come up with a TRULY representative sample input/output set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not robust (what if Random texts starts with `<h2>Time`, this won't match if there is any space betwee the anchor and "Time", and other issues), but perhaps:

```
awk '/^<h2>Time/{$2=$2-5"</h2>"}1' input
```

Comment: This will drop any other HTML tags following the number of seconds, e.g. `</h2></strong>`. And it will not work if any extra fields/words occur before the number, e.g `Time is now 450`.

Comment: How did `$2` get assigned here? And what's in `$1` and `$0`?

Comment: Why is there a trailing `1`?

Comment: @minseong The trailing `1` is equivalent to `{print}`.  It would be the same to do `/^<h2>Time/{$2=$2-5"</h2>"; print}`.  Without it, there would be no output.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/h2/{split($NF,a,"<")} /h2/{$NF=a[1]-5 "</h2>"}1' mat
<h2>Time 450</h2>
Random texts may contain numbers
<h2>Time 455</h2>
Random texts may contain numbers
<h2>Time 478</h2>
Random texts with numbers
<h2>Time 550</h2>
Random texts with numbers
<h2>Time 545</h2>
Random texts may contain numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with Perl:

```
perl -pe '/<h2>/ && s/.* \K(\d+)(.*)/$1-5 .$2/e' file
```

**Output**

```
<h2>Time 450</h2>
Random texts may contain numbers
<h2>Time 455</h2>
Random texts may contain numbers
<h2>Time 478</h2>
Random texts with numbers
<h2>Time 550</h2>
Random texts with numbers
<h2>Time 545</h1>
Random texts may contain numbers
```

Will do its magic on any line containing `<h2>` anywhere in it and will decrement by five the last number on that line that is preceded by a space and also retain anything else that was on the line.

Comment: or `perl -pe 's/<h2>Time \K\d+/$&-5/e'` for first number

Comment: @spasic Agreed, but I was trying to be more robust and only look for a number on the line preceded by a space, so it will work with `<h2>The time is now 450</h2></strong>` for example.